# How to login to Kubernetes using service account?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to perform a simple operation of logging into my cluster to update image of a deployment. I am stuck at the first step. I get an error that connection to `localhost:8080` is refused. Please help.

```
$ chmod u+x kubectl && mv kubectl /bin/kubectl
$ $KUBE_CERT > ca.crt
$ kubectl config set-cluster cfc --server=$KUBE_URL --certificate-authority=ca.crt
Cluster "cfc" set.
$ kubectl config set-context cfc --cluster=cfc
Context "cfc" created.
$ kubectl config set-credentials gitlab-admin --token=$KUBE_TOKEN
User "gitlab-admin" set.
$ kubectl config set-context cfc --user=gitlab-admin
Context "cfc" modified.
$ kubectl config use-context cfc
Switched to context "cfc".
$ echo "Deploying dashboard with version extracted from tag ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
Deploying dashboard with version extracted from tag dev-1.0.4-22
$ kubectl get pods
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Comment: I think the first question to ask is: is your kubernetes controller really on localhost:8080?

Comment: No, the first question to ask is whether all those commands resulted in the thing you expected, which one can verify with `kubectl config view` before the `get pods`; also, modern versions of GitLab have built-in support for working with Kubernetes clusters -- are you doing your integration by hand on purpose?

Comment: No, @MatthewLDaniel. I am new in Kubernetes and I am just trying to set up a basic pipeline but I did not find good tutorials on how to do it. I tried their Auto DevOps, but it seems very complex to me.

Comment: [Their docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.2/ce/user/project/clusters/index.html#add-existing-kubernetes-cluster) are a good start, and you don't need to use Auto DevOps, just add [`only: kubernetes: active`](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.2/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#onlykubernetesexceptkubernetes) to turn on the [kubernetes env-vars](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.2/ce/user/project/clusters/index.html#deployment-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you have you connection refused is because your proxy is not started. Try executing code below so kubectl can access the cluster via proxy (localhost:8080).

```
kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*' &
```

Another approach is to use `curl` and operate with your cluster just like in the following example:

```
curl --cacert /path/to/cert -H "Bearer {your token}" "${KUBE_URL}/api"
```